# django background longrunning tasks without celery

Tags: python, django, cron, celery

when writing the django-backend, we abandoned the use of Celery in favor of Process because we failed to cancel already running tasks

but now we have to schedule long-runnning tasks that should be executed every 5 minutes or every 5 hours or every 3 hours (it's not necessary to be able to cancel them, of course, but I REALLY don't want to use celery)

everywhere I saw that periodic tasks from celery were used to solve this problem, I want to find out what alternatives there are, it is important that it is performant and works on both windows and linux

now we use such a code, we are satisfied with everything, except for a potentially bad performance

```
# in tasks/management/commands/work
class Command(BaseCommand): 
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        while(True):
            do_work() # work executed every 3 hours
            time.sleep(60 * 60 * 3) # sleep 3 hours

# in tasks/management/commands/another_work
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        while(True):
           do_another_work() # work executed every 5 hours
           time.sleep(60 * 60 * 5) # sleep 5 hours
```

how terrible is it to have several such tasks with while(True) + sleep in terms of performance?

i wonder what code to solve this problem is at the heart of celery

Comment: If you run that with multiple users it will cause a denial of service. It will lock the django app because django is not asynchronous. I can offer you a little guidance though. What's wrong with a cron job?

Comment: this code does not cause any errors I run "manage.py runserver" in tab 1, "manage.py work" in tab 2 and "manage.py another_work" in tab 3
(maybe i misunderstood something)
cron not works in windows, and I would like to configure when the points will be launched from the project code